# Find the range of values of p for the equation to have real roots?

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

Question 7a for my homework said to show that $x=-1$ is a solution of $x^3+px^2+px+1=0$. I just did that by using synthetic division.

Question 7b however says "hence find the range of values of $p$ for the equation to have real roots." I've never encountered a question like this, and dont know what to do.  It's a 7 mark question out of 36, so I really need help understanding how to answer it.

Comment: Hint: factor out $x + 1$ (you know that -1 is a root, right?). Obtain a quadratic equation. Compute the discriminant.

Comment: Well i thought it would involve the discriminant, but i wansnt sure how to put the equation i have in to the quadratic form

Answer (score 1):

it is the same as 
$$
(x+1) \left(x^2+(p-1) x+1\right)=0
$$
as for quadratic equation we have to require
$$
(p-1)^2-4>0
$$
(say because the roots are $\frac{-(p-1)\pm \sqrt{(p-1)^2-4}}{2}$)

which implies $p>3$ or $p<-1$

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that would get 7 marks or would i have to write every possible value for p?

Comment: @finlx If all real numbers $p > 3$ is part of the solution, do you really think you can write down every possible value for $p$?